# A problem about the union of boundary and the boundary of unions?

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

Let $X$ be a topological space,${A_n}$ be a sequence of subset of $X$, So I want to know the relationship of $∂(\cup_{n=1}^\infty A_n)$ and $\cup_{n=1}^\infty (∂A_n)$. In general,they should have no any relationship. But I want to know they would be euqal 、$\cup$ or $\cap$  if we added some reasonable conditions.

This question results from the following.
We know some classical results of complex analysis are needed that surroundings is region.Such as: the open mapping theorem、The Maximun module principle. Especially, if surroundings only is open set $G$ and we have the superior limit of $f(z)$ tended to every  boundary point of $∂_\infty G$ are bounded by a constant $M$. What results can be obtain?
My thoughts is if everyone boundary point of every component of $G$ also belongs to $∂_\infty G$ we will have $|f(z)|≤M$ for every $z∈G$.